# Is 'private' a C keyword?

Tags: c, private

Are 'private' or 'public' keywords in ANSI C (or any other C for that matter), or were they only added in C++ (and Java, C#, ...)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`private` is not a C89 or C99 keyword.  See [C Programming/Reference Tables on Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Reference_Tables)*.

Also, C has nothing** to do with Java and C# (and, really, not C++ either).  However, the converse is not true -- C++ grew from C, for example.

** Better reference needed!*
*** Actually, [C89 "borrowed" the `const` and `volatile` keywords from C++](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c5.html#3-5-3).  Likewise, C99 "borrowed" the `inline` keyword, and also added `_Bool` and `_Complex` (like C++'s `bool` and`complex`, respectively) <sup>[citation-needed]</sup>.*

Comment: They are evolutions of C, and much of their syntax sprang from C.

Comment: C++ has no imaginary. but you can instead show "const" as another example where C got ideas from C++ (source: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c5.html#3-5-3). another one is function prototypes (#3-5-4)

Comment: @litb, I don't remember The Dark Ages before C99.  I'll update my answer with your information.  (Sorry for the misinformation about imaginary!)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: C99 added an `_Imaginary` keyword, but doesn't require support for imaginary numbers.

Comment: C borrowed the `//` end of line comments from C++ too.

Answer (score 13):

Neither are C keywords, but some people do the following:

```
#define public 
#define private static
```

#### Update:

For those who think it is a bad idea to do the above, I would agree. But it does explain why someone might think `public` or `private` are C keywords.

For those who think it won't compile in C, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define public
#define private static

private void sayHello(void);

public int main(void) {
    sayHello();

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

private void sayHello(void) {
   printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```

For those who think it won't compile in C++, yes the above program will.

#### Update:

Well actually it is undefined behaviour due to this part of the C++ standard:

> A translation unit that includes a
>   header shall not contain any macros
>   that define names declared or defined
>   in that header. Nor shall such a
>   translation unit define macros for
>   names lexically identical to keywords.

So the example above and below are not required to do anything sane in C++, which is a good thing.  My answer still is completely valid for C (until it is proven to be wrong! :-) ).

In the case of a C++ class with private members, you can do something similar (considered an abuse) like this:

**main.c**:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#define private public
#include "message.hpp"

int main() {
    Message msg;

    msg.available_method();
    msg.hidden_method();

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**message.hpp**:

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_H
#define MESSAGE_H

#include <iostream>

class Message {
  private: 
      void hidden_method();

  public: 
      void available_method();
};

inline void Message::hidden_method() {
    std::cout << "this is a private method" << std::endl;
}

inline void Message::available_method() {
    std::cout << "this is a public method" << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

Comment: I didn't say I supported it... some people stick their heads in ovens too... but you might see code that has done it

Comment: It wouldn't compile in C/C++.

Comment: Dan, are you sure? i think it would, but it is UB (undefined behavior) as soon as you include a standard header file. so it's probably not that useful :)

Comment: @litb, It wouldn't compile in common C++ code because "private:" would be turned into ":", which would result in a syntax error. @Dan, C/C++ isn't a language. It would compile fine in C, unless you're including some C++ header (in which case guards should be in place anyway, or the user is insane).

Comment: I believe @TofuBeer was referring to code like this: public void printHelloWorld();  private int messWithGlobals_EVIL(bool areYouSerious);

Comment: static keyword doesn't share private keyword's semantics in C++.  I could #define purple static and make all my methods "purple" and this would be just as useful.

Comment: @Dan I don't see your point... are you saying that my code is wrong in some way (it isn't my code by the way, but I have seen it done before).

Comment: oh wait i was refering to C++ when i said "i think it would, but it is UB". well in C that of course is not UB but alright. @strager, it depends whether you actually include something that uses "public:" of course :) @tofu, so your first program is *not* required to compile.it can fail aswell in C++

Comment: @litb thanks for pointing out that from the standard... updating answer

Answer (score 0):

*static* isn't like *private*, given that you can't read a static variable even in the *constructor* of the *class* (the function which inits members of a struct in C language).

You only can use static variables in the part of the code where they were defined (in a function, a struct, ...).