# Availability of private and protected in C++ structs

Tags: c++, c

Can we use access specifiers - `private` and `protected` - in C++ structs (as opposed to classes)?

Also, do access modifiers exist in C?

Comment: This is a very elementary question, answerable by a quick check of any C++ reference or tutorial.

Comment: [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

Comment: [Is 'private' a C keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623219/is-private-a-c-keyword?rq=1)

Comment: Re-reading the question, it's not as elementary as I thought (I misread it the first time). The answer isn't obvious if you don't know the relationship between structs and classes. (And there's a style issue of whether you *should* use access specifiers in a struct, though that's not what you asked.) If you'll edit the question, I'll withdraw my downvote.

Answer (score 13):

C doesn't have C++style access modifiers. A C `struct` is just a composite object type containing members of other object types.

In C++, a `struct` and a `class` are *almost* identical; the only difference is that struct members are `public` by default, and class members are `private` by default. So this:

```
struct foo {
private:
    // ...
};
```

is equivalent to this:

```
class foo: {
    // ...
};
```

This has been [answered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c).

This implies that the `private`, `public`, and `protected` keywords are equally valid in either a `struct` definition or a `class` definition.

As a matter of programming style, on the other hand, if you're going to be using access modifiers, it's probably best to define your type as a `class` rather than as a `struct`. Opinions will differ on this, but IMHO the `struct` keyword should be used for [POD (Plain Old Data)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Data_Structures) types, or for types that could be defined as `struct`s in C.

C++ structs, strictly speaking, are very different from C structs, and are nearly identical to C++ classes. But if I see something defined in C++ as a `struct`, I expect (or at least prefer) it to be something similar to a C `struct`.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ a structure is the same as class with the only difference that the default scope is public unlike private that is the default scope for class. In `C` access specifiers don't exist but after all what would you use them for?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `public`, `protected` in `private` in C++ structures.

No, the access modifiers don't exist in C.

In C++, the only difference between `class` and `struct` is that the members of a `class` are by default `private`, whereas the members of a `struct` are by default `public`. This means means that a C++ `struct` can have member functions, constructors, overloaded operator and use any other features of a `class`.

Answer (score 1):

`struct` is not very different from `class` in c++. The default visibility is public instead of private. C does not support those.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between a `struct` and a `class` in C++ is that a `struct`'s members are `public` by default and a `class`'s members are `private` by default. You can use access specifiers in both of them, just as you can use anything else in both of them.

There are no access specifiers in C.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we use access specifiers - private and protected - in struct of c++?

Yes. A `struct` is a class; the only difference is the default accessibility (`public` for `struct`, and `private` for `class`) if you don't specify it.

> Also is the use of access modifier allowed in C language also? Does access specifiers really exist in C??

No, C does not have access specifiers.